# Filter only internet traffic to a VMware Fusion VM

Tags: vmware-fusion

I'm running VMware Fusion 6.0.3, the latest version.

I want to allow only internet traffic to my dev VMs, completely isolate them from local servers, but still have internet access, for updates etc.

I know you can use "Private to my Mac"(host only) mode, but this doesn't allow any internet traffic through.

Is there any way to do this? Maybe filter out all local ip traffic..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest changing the underlying firewall settings on the guest system.  Also you should be able to easily manipulate the routing tables to block the networks you do not want a guest system to see.

Comment: Thanks, while this would work, it's not quite the solution I was after. I was hoping there was something I could do host side. Maybe creating a vlan with a filter on it, but I have no experience with this. I'll leave it open for a few more hours, then select your answer if nothing else has come up.